# How, with jQuery do I tell if a website visitor has been to the site before?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I want create a div container with a message for first time visitors to my site. Visitors will read it and click a 'Hide' button to dissapear it forever.

How is this done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about using the [Cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) for jQuery?

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value'); // Create a session cookie ("the_cookie") and set its value to "the_value"
$.cookie('chocolate_chip_cookie', 'the_value', { // create a cookie with all available options
    expires: 7, // expires in seven days
    path: '/', // accessible from the whole site...
    domain: 'jquery.com',
    secure: true // ...but only on a secure connection
});
$.cookie('the_cookie', null); // delete the session cookie
```

Comment: I am trying to use the cookie plugin without much luck.My code so far is:

var alert = $.cookie('beenHereBefore');
//if cookie has a value of 'yes', hide the alert otherwise if it doesn't have that value, display it and set a cookie value of 'yes' on click
    if (alert == 'yes') {
     $("#alert").hide();
    } else {
        $("#alert").fadeIn("2000");    
  $("#alert").click(function(){
   $(this).slideUp("400");
      $.cookie('beenHereBefore', 'yes');
  });
 }

It doesn't work,any thoughts?

Comment: I have my setup on JSBIN, would you mind checking it over. It seems to work, but I'm not sure I'm hiding the element properly and I don't know if the code could be optimised.

http://jsbin.com/obutu

Many thanks

Comment: Your code is all right, but if you want to eliminate that flicker appearing on subsequent visits, you'd probably better go with setting the CSS of #alert to display: none. jQuery will automatically show the element when you call fadeIn: http://jsbin.com/igube

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by:

1. Setting a cookie.
2. Storing the status in a session.

You can do 1. with JavaScript but also with PHP. 2. can only be accomplished server-side with e.g. PHP.

This tutorial may be helpful:
http://www.shopdev.co.uk/blog/cookies-with-jquery-designing-collapsible-layouts/

Comment: Could I use the visitor's IP address instead?